# Conversion of VB Variable Types

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

I'm experimenting with learning how conversions work between variable types.  Right now, I'm looking at using one conversion inside a Try/Catch (for values that can't convert).  Is there a way to have a string representation of a value (obtained from a TextBox), convert it to a test type, and then see how that converts to all the other VB standard types in a loop?  Or even better if there is a resource that already does this.

I can do this, but the code is very close to being repetitive and I'm hoping for a loop of some kind to simplify and shorten it.

Comment: Typically conversions happen because the user submits text and the code/app converts to a specific other types (int, date etc).  There isnt usually a choice involved, so more explanation and some sample code would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no such thing as `variable type` in VB.net. May be you confusing with `object variables` - but this is not the same thing

```
Dim o As Object
o = 1 ' integer
```

The type that is stored in `o` is still `integer`. It is boxed.

```
Dim i As Integer = CInt(o)
```

You just un-boxed it. It works because `object` is lowest of types and all other derive from it. So, it can "box" any other type.

In UI we use text boxes to collect data. Text boxes can contain only string. And unless you writing these strings to a file like `txt` or `xml` you usually need to convert these strings to a type you use in application.

```
Dim port as Integer = Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text)
```

This is not really the area where you can determine, what type is in that text box. You really need to know upfront - what are you expecting there? You can test your text for being one type or another by using

```
Integer.TryParse
Date.TryParse
.....TryParse
.............
```

But the thing is, some data can successfully pass this test fro multiple types.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. While it is possible to declare variables of type `type` and use them in a loop, these cannot be used in declarations or DirectCast.

```
Dim types() As Type = {GetType(Integer), GetType(Double)}
Dim testType As Type = GetType(Double)
```

The easiest way might be to test each value individually something like this (although you'll probably want a try-catch for each or all the items).

```
Dim xInteger As Integer
xInteger = TextBox1.Text
s &= "Integer: " & xInteger.ToString & vbcrlf ' or some test

Dim xDouble As Double
xDouble = TextBox1.Text
s &= "Double" & ": " & xDouble.ToString & vbcrlf
...
```